# что за wasm файл и как его расшифровать?

Tags: javascript, wasm

Заметил на одном сайте помимо .js скриптов, подгружается файл .wasm
Текст в нем нечитаем. Я пробовал его заблокировать и много контента на сайте теряется.
скажите как его можно прочитать? преобразовать к читаемому виду?

содержимое

asm   €(      ~~`~`   `~` `|`|| `~~~`~ `}` | `~` ~~ `}` | `|` |`|`~`|` ~`~~`|`|`~||`||`~|јwbg__wbindgen_json_parse  wbg__wbindgen_object_drop_ref wbg(__wbg_instanceof_Window_c4b70662a0d2c5ec wbg__wbg_document_1c64944725c0d81d wbg.__wbg_instanceof_HtmlDocument_1faa18f5a2da6fb3 wbg__wbg_cookie_becfe81fc969a9ff wbg __wbg_newnoargs_be86524d73f67598  wbg__wbg_call_888d259a5fefc347  wbg__wbg_self_c6fbdfc2918d5e58 wbg__wbg_window_baec038b5ab35c54 wbg!__wbg_globalThis_3f735a5746d41fbd wbg__wbg_global_1bc0b39582740e95 wbg__wbindgen_is_undefined wbg__wbindgen_object_clone_ref wbg__wbindgen_debug_string wbg__wbindgen_throw ­

и там еще много, примерно на 150кб

Comment: [Что внутри у .wasm-файла? Знакомство с wasm-decompile](https://temofeev.ru/info/articles/chto-vnutri-u-wasm-fayla-znakomstvo-s-wasm-decompile/)

Comment: это ж web-assembly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто вставьте сюда файлик [WebAssembly to C decompiler](https://wwwg.github.io/web-wasmdec/) и получите код на C.

Или запустите на своём компьютере: [исходный код декомпилера](https://github.com/wwwg/wasmdec).

Comment: Что-то сервис не работает если подавать данные в виде буфера Uint8Array.

Comment: ниче не выходит. выдало ;; "lorem_bg.wasm" (Selected wasm binary file)
видимо бинарный надо сначало преобразовать во что то понятное

Comment: llvm может хорошо оптимизировал алгоритм.

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг Ну дизассемблер тоже не дает гарантий получения чистейшего Си кода. Хотя вы можете попробовать. [Их услуга платная](https://hex-rays.com/ida-pro/).

Comment: вобщем помогла эта утилита
https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt
и все получилось